# Install mongodb php driver on mediatemple dv 4.0

Tags: mongodb, mediatemple, nosql

By following the official instructions http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix and this post http://blog.phy5ics.com/2010/03/27/installing-mongodb-on-mediatemple-dv/ I've just about managed to get mongodb installed on MediaTemples DV 4.0 server (I think).

I am however having problems installing the PHP driver http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center

In SSH I get this:

> [root@xxx]# cd /var/tmp
>   [root@xxx]# pecl install mongo
>   downloading mongo-1.1.4.tgz ...
>   Starting to download mongo-1.1.4.tgz (68,924 bytes)
>   .................done: 68,924 bytes
>   18 source files, building
>   running: phpize
>   Configuring for:
>   PHP Api Version:         20090626
>   Zend Module Api No:      20090626
>   Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
>   **/usr/bin/phpize: /var/tmp/mongo/build/shtool: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied**
>   **Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.**
>
> **ERROR: `phpize' failed**

I am logged in as the root user - I don't understand why it's failing and what steps I need to take to install the PHP driver?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From media temple support: Need to create a temporary directory (/root/tmpz):

> $ mkdir /root/tmpz
> $ mount --host /root/tmpz /tmp
> $ umount /tmp; umount /var/tmp
> $ pecl install mongo
>
> Build complete.
> Don't forget to run 'make test'.
>
> running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4" install
> Installing shared extensions:     /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr/lib64/php /modules/
> running: find "/var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4" | xargs ls -dils
> 69094140   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4
> 69275176   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr
> 69275177   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr/lib64
> 69290445   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr/lib64/php
> 69290447   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr/lib64/php/modules
> 69290448 676 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 684126 Feb 22 13:40 /var/tmp/pear-build-root/install-mongo-1.1.4/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so
>
> Build process completed successfully
> Installing '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so'
> install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.1.4
> configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
> You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands on your server's command line:

```
$ mkdir /root/tmp
$ mount --bind /root/tmp /tmp
$ umount /tmp; umount /var/tmp
$ pecl install mongo
```

A few things:

- `/root/tmp` is just an arbitrary temp directory. You can use whatever you want, provided it exists.
- Some instructions say to use `--host` instead of `--bind`. On RHEL/CentOS `mount` says `--host` is an unrecognized option.
- If you're on a VM, it's likely that you'll have to do this each time you restart your VM/Container.

*For Media Temple customers, I can confirm that this works on both (dv) and (ve) servers with CentOS 5 and 6.*

Comment: this helped A LOT but I broke my server temporarily by not unmounting and remounting back to the original settings after running the install. I just had to: umount /tmpz; mount --bind /root/tmp /tmp;after running the mongo install

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to remount `/tmp` unless you deleted the `/root/tmpz` folder afterwards. I'm glad you figured it out, though!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `php-dev` installed? `phpize` is basically "compiling" the MongoDB driver, but unless you have the -dev installed, this may not work.